# How to passing value from a dropdown list component in a User information edit page?

Tags: react-native, return, react-navigation, dropdown

[image: 1]

I insert dropdown list component from extra file
"<Option_Gender />""import Option_Gender from "../components/OptionBar/Option_Gender";"

like this.

I only know to return value for TextInput:

```
<TextInput
                placeholder = "Name:"
                value = {name}
                onChangeText = {(text) => setName(text)}
                style = {styles.BlockStyle}
                placeholderTextColor= 'grey'
                />
```

But I don't know how to return value for this optionbar...

I have tried to return value in the Option_Gender file directly but it seems will cause a conflict...

Answer (score 0):

I can only solve it by directly copying the code in Option_Gender to this page...Hope to have it this way because it puts the option function in a separate file.